# Ubuntu giving error in VM

Tags: 12.04, installation, virtualization

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 in many Virtual PC's But every time Getting same error's. Don't know why?

Here are some screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm using 20.GB for Ubuntu installation & 512 Ram But it says you don't have 4 GB free space.

And if it pass hard disk process Part it ll give error on other part.

Please let me know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a computer. I fixed it by selecting COMPATIBLE MODE in the BIOS. It will disable AICH or OICH or RAID and just leave everything as IDE or LEGACY as well as other options in their more compatible modes.